# How to protect JavaScript code, make it only accessible for certain domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript I want to limit it to run in certain domain. For example I have

```
javascript:(a=(b=document).createElement('script')).src='https://hello.com/js.php',b.body.appendChild(a);void(0)
```

I have the above code that should work only on http://helloworld.com. If some one else tries to access my JS files via https://hello.com/js.php they should not see my JavaScript inside it.

Or can you recommend me any obfuscator that cannot be deobfuscated?

Comment: Obfuscaters can always be made more readable.

Comment: hmm then give me some idea to protect my js

Comment: If you don't want your javascript to be read, don't render it to the client. Filter it server side.

Comment: Why are you so afraid of your javascript being read? You have to realise the client has to reach and interpet it at some point, so complete safety is not possible. Remember the main use of a javascript minimizer is to reduce file size, not to obfuscate.

Comment: An "obfuscator that cannot be deobfuscated" creates code that can never be read by your Javascript engine, and that thus cannot work. Pretty obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want other domains to access your JS files, you can prevent hotlinking through an `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.js$ http://mysite.com/no-hotlinks.js [L]
```

You can allow many domains to access JS files by adding more rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?anothersite\.com/ [NC]
```

But, if you want to prevent access from Web browsers, you cannot do it.

Comment: thank you...how to add two or more domain to allow it to read

Comment: As I was saying in the answer, though, HTTP_REFERER is easily spoofed

Comment: @nico It would require that each client connecting to the blocked domains spoofs HTTP_REFERER. Am I wrong?

Comment: @alessandro1997: not each client necessarily (that won't happen). But if someone wants to bypass the block it can change do it just by header spoofing (that, nowadays, means simply installing a browser addon...)

Answer (score 2):

Anyone will have access to your JS since its output is a public web page.

Your design has a bug somewhere.

Comment: hmm yea,,,but i am not using javascript in websites...i am just using in adress bar like javascript:bla bla

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP (or any other server-side language) to serve the JS files.

So instead of calling `myfile.js` you will call `generateJS.php?val=15` and then you'll have an array associating val to the correct filename.

The actual JS filename will not be seen from outside and you can check the domain in PHP (although headers can be spoofed).

Obviously people will still be able to get the source of your JS in this way, but, if you really think that is a problem you should not use JS in the first place.

Comment: I have tested: the ```$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']``` is not set when accessing the file through the ```<script>``` tag.

Comment: hmm yea,,,but i am not using javascript in websites...i am just using in adress bar like javascript:bla bla

Comment: @vishnu: so maybe you should better explain what you are trying to achieve